# Private PoA deployment leads to 'invalid gas used' error

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-deployment, private-blockchain, gas, poa

I'm trying to deploy a contract to a private clique chain running on two devices (laptop and raspi). Deploying the contract when running multiple nodes on a single device worked fine as per usual, both via truffle migrate when directly deploying from the js console inside Geth (PC: 1.9.19, PI: 1.8.27). The nodes happily mine away, however, when I try to deploy the contract to the multi-device chain, it repeatedly throws the following error:

```
########## BAD BLOCK #########

Chain config: {ChainID: 12345 Homestead: 0 DAO: <nil> DAOSupport: false EIP150: 0 EIP155: 0 EIP158: 0 Byzantium: 0 Constantinople: 0 ConstantinopleFix: 0 Engine: clique}


Number: 301

Hash: 0xea47e7c5b1200e51752ff7575e08fc1b0f8f96cf2074f7db4b9dabe8933b9394

 0: cumulative: 406318 gas: 406318 contract: 0x2d34066AA9FCbb0aD41889F97A84008d0975B3C2 status: 1 tx: 0x7963ddc11b391ffca9a8fcfe55b8daeafe87c3dd9b57118f99ce1763230f3f13 logs: \[\] bloom: 0... state: 
Error: invalid gas used (remote: 342202 local: 406318)

##############################
```

I have no clue where this difference in gas used comes from.

Things I've tried so far:

- deploy from signing node
- deploy from non-signing node
- deploy via truffle migrate
- deploy manually via bytecode

Any clues on why this occurs and how it can be fixed?

Comment: The error means one node has produced a block that is not valid to the other node. Are both nodes on the same geth version? If that is correct you should report the error to geth developers so they can investigate further.

Comment: The error was due to using different geth versions, thank you for the advice! While I still wonder how these cause different gas consumptions, updating fixed it.
Updating geth on the Pi is a bit of a pain, so here are two tutorials in case someone else has this issue:
Geth: https://kauri.io/running-an-ethereum-full-node-on-a-raspberrypi-4-m/9695fcca217f46feb355245275835fc0/a
Golang (also needed): https://www.e-tinkers.com/2019/06/better-way-to-install-golang-go-on-raspberry-pi/

Comment: Some forks had changes to opcode pricing, it appears it was activated on the pc but it wasn't on the rpi, it worked while no smart contract used those opcodes. Mixing geth versions may cause problems, usually it is assumed you are on the most recent version.

Comment: Good to know, thanks for the explanation!